# How to define maps in Groovy

Tags: java, loops, groovy, dictionary

I want to make a series of maps, such as `map1, map1, map3, etc...`  and I want to do this with a loop.  This does not work:

```
for (i = 1; i++){

    def map[ i ]
```

how can I make this happen?

Comment: Why did this post get -3 votes?  Because of the missing clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In groovy, [maps](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections#Collections-Maps) need any number of key/value pairs.  Also, your for-loop is missing a clause.  Try this:

```
maps = [] // A list which will store maps.
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
  maps[i] = [i:i]
}
maps[0] // => [i:0]
maps[1] // => [i:1] ...
maps[9] // => [i:9]
```

Comment: 'maps' in this case would be a List, not an Array

Comment: hey thanks, this gets at what I'm after!  But to go deeper, say I want multiple 'maps'  like the "Array which will store maps" you defined above... How to do that?

Comment: Also, maps with no keys are perfectly valid. The phrase _'..any number of key/value pairs..'_ seems to suggest you have to have at least one... But that might just be me being overly picky ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
def listOfMaps = (1..10).collect { [:] }
```

That will make a list containing 10 maps

If that's not what you want, you are going to have to explain what you are trying to do ;-)